# Spambots keeps creating user signups even after reCAPTCHA v2 (invisible) and Honeypot integration - what else can I do?

Tags: forms, recaptcha, spam, spam-prevention, honeypot

I integrated my website with **reCAPTCHA v2 (invisible)** and also **Honeypot** on my customer sign up form and I'm still receiving spam signups daily, I even set the reCAPTCHA to the **Most Secure** option.

I think the biggest issue for me is how this is affecting my "**email reputation**" because the spambots are using a mix of real and fake email addresses.

I was also going to try to integrate with a "**verify email address**" service but if the email address is valid it will still be an issue because the actual user didn't sign up on my website.

Is there any other methods I could try using? Or is there a free scan available that checks for vulnerabilities on forms?

Is what's happening considered **SQL injection** or **XSS** attacks on my site, or are these spambots just repeatedly beating my **reCAPTCHA** and **Honeypot** spam protection methods?

All signups are using these crazy values for the **first name (e.g. xPwRdKQfBmDHriuL)** and **last name (e.g. rWFmMQkhbqeOKf)** values.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you verifying the reCAPTCHA token on the server?

Comment: Yes, I’m validating on the server too.

Comment: I'm still having the same issue, is there a way I can have my developer add code to see if we can see where the issue is?  I was even going to also have him add a verification question like "What is 2+2?" as another layer of protection but I feel like I will have the same issue if they're already getting around reCAPTCHA and Honeypot.

Answer (score 0):

Are the bots alternating IP addresses? You could build in a check that logs IP visits per hour and limit the allowed visits per IP address per hour.

Just as an example, 50 visits (or posts) from a single IP are allowed per hour. After that, you serve that IP a 404 status. Which in turn also could trigger the bot to abandon the page or list your page in it's database as a dead page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Yes, I’ve been monitoring the IPs but they’re coming from all over so it’s difficult to block any specific IPs.  I think I’m going to try to either add a verification question (e.g. what’s 2+2=?) or use a email verification code that has to be entered before the form is allowed to be submitted; similar to how I saw the TikTok Ads sign up page work, seems like this method could work well.